# Scrapy & ASPX site - why does it only loop over first page?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to pull data from this site: https://inform.alabama.gov/employeesearch.aspx. When I run this code currently, it just pulls data from "Page$1" repeatedly. The loop doesn't actually appear to be iterating the query. This is my first script in Python as well as Scrapy, so I am sure I am missing something fundamental here...

What is the correct way to take the response from one request and pass the data pulled from it to the next?

This site also doesn't have a "Next" button, so I used the num_pages variable to set the max. Open to suggestions on how to make that dynamic.

```py
from scrapy import FormRequest, Spider
from scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror import HttpError
from twisted.internet.error import DNSLookupError
from twisted.internet.error import TimeoutError, TCPTimedOutError


class EmployeesSpider(Spider):
    name = 'employees'
    start_urls = ['https://inform.alabama.gov/employeesearch.aspx']
    num_pages = 5  # 661

    def parse(self, response):
        for i in range(1, self.num_pages):
            yield FormRequest(
                url='https://inform.alabama.gov/employeesearch.aspx',
                method="POST",
                dont_filter=True,
                headers={
                    "authority": "inform.alabama.gov",
                    "cache-control": "max-age=0",
                    "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
                    "origin": "https://inform.alabama.gov",
                    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36",
                    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
                    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
                    "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
                    "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
                    "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
                    "referer": "https://inform.alabama.gov/employeesearch.aspx",
                    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9"
                },
                formdata=self.get_formdata(response, i),
                callback=self.parse_results,
                errback=self.failure)

    def get_formdata(self, response, page_num):
        eventargument = 'Page%24' + str(page_num)

        viewstate = response.css(
            'input#__VIEWSTATE::attr(value)').get()
        if viewstate is None:
            viewstate = ''

        viewstategen = response.css(
            'input#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR::attr(value)').get()
        if viewstategen is None:
            viewstategen = ''

        eventvalidation = response.css(
            'input#__EVENTVALIDATION::attr(value)').get()
        if eventvalidation is None:
            eventvalidation = ''

        formdata = {
            '__EVENTTARGET': 'ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24GridView1',
            '__EVENTARGUMENT': eventargument,
            '__VIEWSTATE': viewstate,
            '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': viewstategen,
            '__EVENTVALIDATION': eventvalidation,
            'ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24txt_FirstName': '',
            'ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24txt_LastName': '',
            'ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ddl_Agency': 'Not+Selected',
            'ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24txt_Phone': '',
        }
        return formdata

    def parse_results(self, response):
        for employee in response.xpath('//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1"]//tr'):
            yield {
                'name': employee.xpath('./td[1]/text()').get(),
                'email': employee.xpath('./td[1]/span/a/text()').get(),
                'org': employee.xpath('./td[2]/text()').get(),
                'phone': employee.xpath('./td[3]/span/a/text()').get(),
            }

    def failure(self, failure):
      # log all failures
        self.logger.error(repr(failure))

        # in case you want to do something special for some errors,
        # you may need the failure's type:

        if failure.check(HttpError):
            # these exceptions come from HttpError spider middleware
            # you can get the non-200 response
            response = failure.value.response
            self.logger.error('HttpError on %s', response.url)

        elif failure.check(DNSLookupError):
            # this is the original request
            request = failure.request
            self.logger.error('DNSLookupError on %s', request.url)

        elif failure.check(TimeoutError, TCPTimedOutError):
            request = failure.request
            self.logger.error('TimeoutError on %s', request.url)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send a search form request (`__EVENTTARGET=ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btn_Search`) first and next iterate result pages (`__EVENTTARGET=ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1`):

```
def parse(self, response):
    # for i in range(1, 2):
    formdata = self.get_formdata(response, 0)
    formdata['__EVENTTARGET'] = 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btn_Search'
    formdata['__EVENTARGUMENT'] = ''
    yield FormRequest(
        url='https://inform.alabama.gov/employeesearch.aspx',
        method="POST",
        dont_filter=True,
        formdata=formdata,
        callback=self.perform_search,
        errback=self.failure)

def perform_search(self, response):
    for employee in response.xpath('//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1"]//tr'):
        yield {
            'name': employee.xpath('./td[1]/text()').get(),
            'email': employee.xpath('./td[1]/span/a/text()').get(),
            'org': employee.xpath('./td[2]/text()').get(),
            'phone': employee.xpath('./td[3]/span/a/text()').get(),
        }

    # Download search pages starting from #2
    for i in range(2, self.num_pages):
        formdata = self.get_formdata(response, i)
        yield FormRequest(
            url='https://inform.alabama.gov/employeesearch.aspx',
            method="POST",
            dont_filter=True,
            formdata=formdata,
            callback=self.parse_results,
            cb_kwargs={
                'page': i,
            },
            errback=self.failure)

def get_formdata(self, response, page_num):
    eventargument = 'Page$' + str(page_num)

    viewstate = response.css(
        'input#__VIEWSTATE::attr(value)').get()
    if viewstate is None:
        viewstate = ''

    viewstategen = response.css(
        'input#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR::attr(value)').get()
    if viewstategen is None:
        viewstategen = ''

    eventvalidation = response.css(
        'input#__EVENTVALIDATION::attr(value)').get()
    if eventvalidation is None:
        eventvalidation = ''

    formdata = {
        '__EVENTTARGET': 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1',
        '__EVENTARGUMENT': eventargument,
        '__VIEWSTATE': viewstate,
        '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': viewstategen,
        '__EVENTVALIDATION': eventvalidation,
        'ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24txt_FirstName': '',
        'ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24txt_LastName': '',
        'ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ddl_Agency': 'Not+Selected',
        'ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24txt_Phone': '',
    }
    return formdata

def parse_results(self, response, page):
    # with open(f'Samples/Page_{page}.htm', 'wb') as f:
    #    f.write(response.body)

    for employee in response.xpath('//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1"]//tr'):
        yield {
            'name': employee.xpath('./td[1]/text()').get(),
            'email': employee.xpath('./td[1]/span/a/text()').get(),
            'org': employee.xpath('./td[2]/text()').get(),
            'phone': employee.xpath('./td[3]/span/a/text()').get(),
        }
```

Comment: I plugged those functions into my spider class and ran it with 'scrapy crawl employees -O employees.csv', but it didn't actually get any results: the csv populated with every row as ',,,'

Comment: Something is wrong with your implimitation. I have 583 items for 12 pages (https://www.dropbox.com/s/xii191yheft2ao4/employees.csv?dl=0)

Comment: I was able to get data to return by making all the paths in the yield use '//' : employee.xpath('.//td[1]//text()').get()

Comment: but then it skipped pages 2 & 3. Can I see your full file to test it directly on my end?

Comment: What do you mean by "full file"?

Comment: I see what is happening here. It runs the first one and then the csv is populated in reverse order with the loop. 1,5,4,3,2, so all the data was there.  The next issue that I see occurs page 12+. If you run it with 15 pages, then pages 12-15 are not returned. 302 errors for those pages. Something with the request must be fundamentally changing when the pagination transitions from "1-..." to "11-..."

Comment: Sorry but I think that I answered your initial question.

Comment: yes you did. I'm new to SO. should I just mark this as solved and post it as a new question?

Comment: You can post another question (with detailed description and code fragment) if you have another issue.

Answer (score 0):

With the use of cb_kwargs or the old meta you can pass info from one function to next https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html

```
def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.starting_urls:
        yield Request(
            url,
            cb_kwargs={'additional_arguments': dict_map[url]}
        )

def parse(self, response, additional_arguments):
    # Here you can use that additional_argument
    pass
```

Comment: I don't see how to apply this to my use case. This functionality seems to be passing static or request content to the parse function. I need to extract data from the page html response following each request to generate the form data for the next request.